# Why i can't get image file from chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

To the point, i can't call my image using methode like this.

Where's my mistake?

```
'<span style="width:100%;"><img src=' + chrome.extension.getURL('/images/load-data.gif') + '></span>'
```

Comment: Depends on where you want tot use it. If it's on a web page, you need to declare it in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: Oh, im just adding png format, not gif. haha. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** by  [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)

Adding `.gif` format into `web_accessible_resources` :

```
{
  ...
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/*.png",
    "images/*.gif",
  ],
  ...
}
```

Thanks.